# PDF-Print E-Mail in Evolution (flatpak)

Tags: pdf-generation, gnome, flatpak

I am using [Evolution](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/) ([flatpak package](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution/Flatpak)) as a Personal Information Manager. However, when I try to print an E-Mail as .pdf, I have not full access to my filesystem. I can only save the .pdf in some restricted file tree.
I have used the trick to print the .pdf in the `~/.gnupg` folder, and then using the ordinary file manager copy-paste into any folder—But that is no long-term solution.

How could I make the pdf-printer in Evolution have access to the whole filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

If you run into problems like this with a Flatpak application, try using [Flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal) to try configuring different permissions for that application. Doing this, I was able to not only allow Evolution to print to PDF by enabling access to my home directory, but also connect to the print service (CUPS) to actually print emails.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is some kind of bug in Evolution concerning this issue (see [forum](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/evolution-flatpak-printing-email-to-file-gives-directory-error/24800)), whereas in other applications such as Inkscape (flatpak) everything runs smooth.

The quickest fix is to add the option `--filesystem=home` to the running command of Evolution (see [forum](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/evolution-flatpak-cannot-print-emails-to-pdf/11491)), namely,

`flatpak run --filesystem=home org.gnome.Evolution`

Maybe you have to edit your desktop entry of Evolution (See [desktop editor](https://tojaj.com/linux-desktop-menu-editors/))